# 18.04 is very slow and sluggish (PNY 960GB CS900)

Tags: ssd, performance, system

I installed 18.04 at a fan-less mini-pc (1,6 Ghz i3, 8GB Ram, quad-core) right after it was released. That time the whole system was quite comfortably to operate.

After a few months I replaced the original SSD to a bigger one (PNY 960GB CS900)
I used Acronis to backup and restore to the new disk then I used GParted to modify  partition size.

I'm running an IO intensive application that constantly appends to a file (currently 295GB)

SSD currently available 410GB used 490GB

The whole system became constantly a bit slower.
After a few months after changing the SSD I noticed that it considerably slowed down when I started the above mentioned application. 
Now The system is even slow and sluggish after a fresh reboot when no application is running.

Because I'm using SSD I never considered large files being an issue.

I regularly update the node using apt upgrade

Is there anything I can do except a fresh install?

Comment: I'd check the health of the SSD (ie. it's SMART)

Comment: What's the output of `sudo fstrim -av`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! output fstrim  :/ 428,6 GiB (460208263168 bytes) trimmed                      .                      
gsmartcontrol : overall health status: passed, error log: empty, uncorrrectable errors: 0, crc errors: 0

Comment: When I reboot and I execute fstrim again then there is the same message. If I re-execute it again then 0 trimmed. Should I execute it after every reboot?

Comment: System behaves still very slow after fstrim. Is there anything else I can do?